# Trying to print diamond pattern with spaces in between but ends up skewed

Tags: javascript, logic

Been trying to print a diamond pattern with spaces in between, however it ends up getting skewed:

```
function printDiamond(input) {
    if (typeof input === 'number' && input <= 100) {
        //printing columns
        for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++) { //upside pyramid
            for (var b = 1; b <= (input - i); b++) { //prints spaces to position stars
                document.write("&nbsp");
            }
            console.log(document.write, "1")
            for (var a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
                document.write(" ", "*"); //prints space + stars
            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }
        for (var i = input - 1; i >= 1; i--) { //downside pyramid
            for (var b = 1; b <= input - i; b++) { //prints spaces to position stars
                document.write("&nbsp");
            }
            for (var a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
                document.write(" ", "*"); //prints space + stars
            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }
}
printDiamond(5);
```

Output:
[Skewed diamond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRHdx.png)

I tried fixing by using " " instead of "&nbsp" for the positioning so that the spacing will even out.

```
function printDiamond(input) {

    if (typeof input === 'number' && input <= 100) {
        //printing columns
        for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++) { //upside pyramid
            for (var b = 1; b <= (input - i); b++) { //prints spaces to position stars
                document.write(" ");
            }
            console.log(document.write, "1")
            for (var a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
                document.write(" ", "*"); //prints space + stars
            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }
        for (var i = input - 1; i >= 1; i--) { //downside pyramid
            for (var b = 1; b <= input - i; b++) { //prints spaces to position stars
                document.write(" ");
            }
            for (var a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
                document.write(" ", "*"); //prints space + stars
            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }
}
printDiamond(5);
```

But the first nested loops (used for positioning) of upper and lower pryramid seems not to be working with " ".

Output: [Stars without positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHksu.png)

Using number to check spaces: [space check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxmC.png)

Advices will be much appreciated! Tried a lot of trial and error on this but to no avail..

Comment: Does the diamond still appear skewed if you change the document to a different font, for example `monospace` or Courier New?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a font that does not display spaces and asterisks with equal width. Consider a [monospace font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) instead.

Moreover, use only `&nbsp;` instead of regular spaces or set `white-space: pre` on the container as consecutive whitespace is not shown by default in HTML.

```js
function printDiamond(input) {
  if (typeof input === 'number' && input <= 100) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
      for (var b = 1; b <= (input - i); b++) {
        document.write("&nbsp");
      }
      for (var a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
        document.write("&nbsp;", "*");
      }
      document.write("<br>");
    }
    for (var i = input - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      for (var b = 1; b <= input - i; b++) {
        document.write("&nbsp");
      }
      for (var a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
        document.write("&nbsp;", "*");
      }
      document.write("<br>");
    }
  }
}
printDiamond(5);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```